# How to request list of apps contained within the Managed Play Store Collections using Android Management API

Tags: android-management-api

In regards to the Android Management API and the managed Google Playstore, is there a GET request to retrieve all of the applications within a collection?

For example, if I have these three applications added to the My Work App collection within the managed Google Play iFrame, is there a GET request to access the applications within this collection? If there is another way to retrieve the collection data please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to retrieve all the applications in your app collection. If it is possible for you to share your use case, it may be helpful in finding a solution to your problem.