# How are collections used in the Android Management API - Managed Play Store?

Tags: android-management-api

Within the Android Management API - Managed Play Store, there are collections which can contain specific applications. How are these collections supposed to be used? I felt like the documentation was lacking in this area. I am trying to figure out how these collections work in comparison to putting applications into a policy. With a managed device, is it expected that these collections show up in the device's Play Store?

Answer (score 1):

The [Organize apps page](https://developers.google.com/android/management/apps#organize-apps) lets IT admins organize apps into collections (also called clusters). For example, an IT admin can create an Essentials collection for frequently used apps or an Expenses collection for apps related to tracking expenses, logging travel, etc. Collections are displayed in the Play Store homepage on user's devices.

On user's devices, the Play Store app only displays apps from a collection that are available for the user (or device), which means that if an app is not included in your policy, it will not appear on the user’s device

To integrate IFrame into your console please check this (documentation)[https://developers.google.com/android/management/apps#add_the_iframe_to_your_console]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there an HTTP call to access items in a Collection for easy addition to a device policy? I created this question in this thread if you would rather reply there: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68401200/how-to-request-list-of-apps-contained-within-the-managed-play-store-collections

Comment: I'm looking for the Organize apps page, but I cannot find it. I see from [the doc](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/9146438?hl=en) that there's supposed to be a button 'Organize apps' on the left, but my https://play.google.com/work page shows only 'My Managed Apps', 'Shop', and 'Updates'. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain it better:

Firstly, set your playstoremode to WHITELIST

Then, in your policy include all the apps as AVAILABLE or FORCE_INSTALLED which you selected in your cluster (collections)